# Is it safe to modify an Object inside for (..in..) loop?

Tags: javascript

```
A = { 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5 };
for (var i in A) {
    console.log(i);
    if (A[i] == 4) delete A[i], A[7] = 7;
    if (A[i] == 2) delete A[i], A[0] = 0;
    if (A[i] == 7) console.log('seven');
    if (A[i] == 0) console.log('zero');
}
console.log(A);
```

This seems to work, but I do not know the details of the implementation of the for(..in..) loop to be sure it is safe in most conditions.

[See also here the same question about arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832221/is-it-safe-to-modify-an-array-in-for-in-loop)

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According the MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Deleted.2C_added_or_modified_properties) you should not try to do this

> If a property is modified in one iteration and then visited at a later
>   time, its value in the loop is its value at that later time.
>
> A property that is deleted before it has been visited will not be
>   visited later.
>
> Properties added to the object over which iteration is
>   occurring may either be visited or omitted from iteration.
>
> In general it is best not to add, modify or remove properties from the object
>   during iteration, other than the property currently being visited.
>
> There is no guarantee whether or not an added property will be
>   visited, whether a modified property (other than the current one) will
>   be visited before or after it is modified, or whether a deleted
>   property will be visited before it is deleted.

So while it might have worked in your tests so far it might not always.

Answer (score 0):

By using that method you could potentially skip over indexes of `A` because as you delete elements, the indexes of all other elements will shift by -1 and may then by missed by the iterator.  Instead, you could create a second list and then only add the good values from `A` to it.